# Как сверстать подменю со скруглением?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как реализовать подобное меню? Сложность заключаются в закруглении никак не получается сделать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваши наработки, желательно в мини-примере.

Comment: Или дайте ссылку на сайт где вы этот меню нашли)

Comment: @ПростаMiha а вдруг это коварный дизайнер нарисовал, чтобы верстальщик мучился? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробовал сделать такое скругление через псевдоэлемент. Не знаю, насколько действительно такой код применим. Плохо знаю clip-path.

1. У заголовка меню псевдоэлемент в правом нижнем углу.
2. Там нарисован круг, из которого и получается скругление.
3. Через clip-path обрезано лишнее, чтобы осталось только скругление.
4. Если нужна у всего этого еще и граница, то она реализована в скруглении через outline и его смещение ближе к центру.

```css
html {
  /* Основные параметры меню*/
  --border-radius: 20px; /* Радиус скруглений, в том числе внутренний*/
  --border-width: 2px; /* Толщина границы у всего блока меню, если есть */
  --border-color: white; /* Цвет границы */
  --background-color: dodgerblue; /* Цвет фона блока меню */
  
  /* Фон страницы */
  background-color: #ddd;
}

h1, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  border: var(--border-width) solid var(--border-color);
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  /* Убираем нижние скругления у заголовка */
  border-radius: var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius) 0 0;
  /* Убираем нижнюю границы у заголовка*/
  border-bottom: none;
}

p {
  /*   Убираем левое верхнее скругление у пункта меню  */
  border-radius: 0 var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius);
  /*   Сдвигаем пункт меню немного вверх, чтобы скрыть границу */
  position: relative;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--border-width));
  /*   Помещаем пункт меню назад, чтобы не была видна граница */
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Сам элемент с внутренним скруглением */
h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /*   Расположение в левом нижнем углу заголовка */
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--border-radius));
  right: calc(-3 * var(--border-radius));
  /*   Размер квадратом вдвое больше нужного радиуса скругления */
  width: calc(2 * var(--border-radius));
  height: calc(2* var(--border-radius));
  /*   Форма круга */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*   Граница элемента образует фон всего меню */
  border: var(--border-radius) solid var(--background-color);
  /*   Обрезаем лишнее треугольником, чтобы остался только кусочек со скруглением */
  clip-path: polygon(24% 50%, 24% 75%, 50% 75%);
  /*   Видимая граница за счет outline, который сдвигаем ближе к центру */
  outline: var(--border-width) solid var(--border-color);
  outline-offset: calc(-1 * (var(--border-width) + var(--border-radius)));
}
```

```html
<h1>Контакты</h1>
<p>Связаться с нами можно по телефону</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну мне приходит в голову вот так, но не сглаживание у скруглений что-то не очень вышло:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, grey, white, gray);
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: left;
}

section {
  display: contents;
}

div {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: none;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
}

a {
  grid-row: 1;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a::before, a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: none;
}

a::before {
  right: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 0;
  border-color: transparent red red transparent;
  box-shadow: .5em .5em 0 0 antiquewhite;
}

a::after {
  left: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent red red;
  box-shadow: -.5em .5em 0 0 antiquewhite;
}

section:hover a {
  background: antiquewhite;
  border-color: red red transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

section:hover a::before, section:hover a::after {
  display: block;
}

section:hover div {
  display: block;
  background: antiquewhite;
  border-color: red;
}

section:first-child > div {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

section:last-child > div {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

section:first-child > a::before, section:last-child > a::after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <section>
    <a>Каталог изделий</a>
    <div>Каталог изделий Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed libero repudiandae, dolore iste ratione tempore delectus perferendis eveniet sint? Itaque voluptatibus fugit consectetur obcaecati aliquid vel eius. Ea, rerum quis!</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a>ГОСТы</a>
    <div>ГОСТы Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed libero repudiandae, dolore iste ratione tempore delectus perferendis eveniet sint? Itaque voluptatibus fugit consectetur obcaecati aliquid vel eius. Ea, rerum quis!</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a>Рекоммендации</a>
    <div>Рекоммендации Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed libero repudiandae, dolore iste ratione tempore delectus perferendis eveniet sint? Itaque voluptatibus fugit consectetur obcaecati aliquid vel eius. Ea, rerum quis!</div>
  </section>
</nav>
```